# SSIS Script Component Does Not Recognize Dts.Variables Namespace

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I want to read the rows inside a user object, but when I try to fill it to a DataTable, `Dts.Variables` is not a recognized namespace.

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::CRMDataSet"].Value);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //insert what you want to do here
    }
}
```

The available namespaces are not related as well.

[image]

May I know how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check on your variables that you have created and the scope is the right one: either package or the script task name.
Also what is your data type: if you have table data then it should be object.

Example:

[image: image variables]